# Transform method in the Expression shape throws an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Am using VisualStudio 2010. In my orchestration am using expressions to dynamically transform messages.

```
construct outputmsg    
{
 System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("INTERFACE","Entered construct ..." );
 transform (outputmsg) = oMap(Inputmsg);
 System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("INTERFACE","after transform ..." );
}
```

Now I encounter the following error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

In BizTalk eventlog I noticed => Entered construct .. ,which means its entering construct method. But after that exception is thrown.

I think "transform" is giving an error.

I have the corresponding mapping file (used in transform) in my solution

Where am I going wrong? Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: To narrow it down, you should attach Visual Studio to BTSNTSvc.exe and see where it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialized oMap variable using

oMap = typeof(MapName);

See more details on
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa950573.aspx

Comment: Yes Vikas. I initialized oMap variable using oMap = System.Type.GetType(MapName); where MapName is supposed to "TypeName" of a Map. Instead I gave map name. I went wrong here. I corrected it. It works fine now. Thank you :)